# C - Unix pipe, close() affects the output?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I encountered a strange bug when working with unix pipes. I wrote a short program to showcase the problem.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int argc, char*args[]){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork()");
        exit(1);
    }else if(pid == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
        size_t len = strlen(msg) + 1; // +1 for null char
        write(fd[1], msg, len);
        while(1){/*does other work*/}
    }else{
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    pid = fork();
    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork()");
        exit(1);
    }else if(pid == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
        size_t len = strlen(msg) + 1; // +1 for null char
        write(fd[1], msg, len);
        while(1){/*does other work*/}
    }else{
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    //close(fd[1]);
    sleep(5);

    const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
    size_t len = strlen(msg) + 1; // +1 for null char
    char str[len];
    fcntl(fd[0],F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if(read(fd[0], str, len)<=0){
        printf("Nothing from child\n"); 
    }
    /*does other work*/
    fcntl(fd[0],F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if(read(fd[0], str, len)<=0){
        printf("Nothing from child\n"); 
    }
    printf("finished read\n");
    /*does other work*/
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The parent process forks two children and creates a pipe. Two child processes write to the pipe, parent read from the pipe.

Parent process should recover all information wrote by child.

However, when I run the above program, parent prints out

```
Nothing from child
finished read
```

Why?

Interestingly, if I write a single close(fd[1]) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int argc, char*args[]){
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork()");
        exit(1);
    }else if(pid == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
        size_t len = strlen(msg) + 1; // +1 for null char
        write(fd[1], msg, len);
        while(1){/*does other work*/}
    }else{

    }
    pid = fork();
    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork()");
        exit(1);
    }else if(pid == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
        size_t len = strlen(msg) + 1; // +1 for null char
        write(fd[1], msg, len);
        while(1){/*does other work*/}
    }else{

    }
    close(fd[1]);//HERE IS THE DIFFERENCE
    sleep(5);

    const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
    size_t len = strlen(msg) + 1; // +1 for null char
    char str[len];
    fcntl(fd[0],F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if(read(fd[0], str, len)<=0){
        printf("Nothing from child\n"); 
    }
    /*does other work*/
    fcntl(fd[0],F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if(read(fd[0], str, len)<=0){
        printf("Nothing from child\n"); 
    }
    printf("finished read\n");
    /*does other work*/
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

It works, it also works if I don't have close(fd[1]) at all. I'm at a lost, why would the position of close() affect the reading of pipes?

Comment: Why do you think it's OK to close fd[1] twice?

Comment: In the first example, you close the write side of the pipe before you fork the second child, so that child cannot write into the pipe.  You fix it by moving the close.  What's the question?

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you, I forgot that the second child would have the writing end closed!

Comment: You should always test the return count of `write`. Especially for pipes and sockets, *partial* `write` do happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but this statement is clearly wrong:

```
write(fd[1], "I'm here\n", 256);
```

You are writing 256 bytes from the source buffer, which is a very short static string.  I think you want to say this:

```
const char* msg = "I'm here\n";
size_t len = strlen(msg); // could be strlen(msg)+1 - see discussion in comments.
write(fd[1], "I'm here\n", len);
```

Comment: Eh... when was the last time you output **the null-terminating byte** by means of `write()` or any other I/O function? On terminals, this is okay, but when working with pipes, this can cause severe issues.

Comment: Good point. A real protocol would include some formal way between reader/writer to agree on how to detect the end of the string.  But since he's just calling `read` with a bigger than necessary buffer to receive the message, how would he know how many bytes are in the message?  That's why I originally include the null - so that his `read` wouldn't leave a buffer without a null char.

Comment: You're right. But, if he doesn't write two or more separate strings, then he can simply `read` until EOF and that's it.

Comment: @KemyLand It's absolutely OK to write any byte to a pipe, including null byte. There are no special bytes in Unix files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I've implemented your suggestion (I think), but it's still producing the same behavior.

Comment: @n.m.: I did *never* said that tthe null byte is somehow special. I just stated that doing so can lead to.. eh.. "protocol errors", as I don't think most filter utilities expect that.

Comment: @Rex - You accepted this answer. Does that mean it worked for you? I'm curious because you mentioned above that you were still hitting the issue.

Comment: @KemyLand Standard utilities (find, xargs) read and write null bytes.

Comment: @n.m.: Take, for example, a C program that takes as input a "line", and replaces all occurences of `';'` in that line with `'\0'`. Then, it passes the resulting line to `xargs --null`. The result is a complete mess if the input line contained `'\0'`s. Although the system may not think of null bytes as special, in most cases, both users and programmers do, and, IMHO, that's far more important.

Comment: @KemyLand You can screw up any protocol, no problem with that at all. find -print0 | xargs -0 style pipes work, and you can write your own programs that conform to the same protocol.

Comment: @n.m.: We're getting off-topic. My point is that it isn't correct to assume the reader will accept zero bytes, nothing more.

Comment: @KemyLand OP controls the reader, he knows what it will accept. If you mean any random unknown reader, then no, it isn't correct to assume it will accept null bytes (or spaces or quotes or brackets or the letter Q). This program communicates with one specific reader though. Why should it care about all other readers?

Comment: @n.m.: Because it was this answer that introduced that "write the null byte too" into the mix. It's simply (for what the OP shows) innecessary here. What I meant with "it isn't correct to assume the reader will accept zero bytes" is that you (or me, at least) expect most filter programs to be able to handle printable/showable characters (including whitespaces), but you simply don't expect GCC to accept [ENQ `'\5'`](http://www.asciitable.com/), do you? It's simply better off not to mess with... "special" characters if it can be avoided.

Comment: @KemyLand Let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes, better off that way ;).